# Problems with start application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I try to create simple application using `Auth2` and when I try to run it, It failed with warning:

> 2019-08-08 10:15:36.575  WARN 11920 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.english.learn.config.WebSecurityConfig]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.ResourceServerTokenServicesConfiguration$JwtTokenServicesConfiguration due to org/springframework/boot/bind/RelaxedPropertyResolver not found. Make sure your own configuration does not rely on that class. This can also happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)

**pom.xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.english</groupId>
<artifactId>learn</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>learn</name>
<description>Project for learn english</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.8</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security.oauth/spring-security-oauth2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**WebSecurityConfig:**

```
import com.english.learn.entity.User;
import com.english.learn.repo.UserRepo;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.EnableOAuth2Sso;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.PrincipalExtractor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .mvcMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    public PrincipalExtractor principalExtractor(UserRepo userRepo) {
        return map -> {
            String id = (String) map.get("sub");

            User user = userRepo.findById(id).orElseGet(() -> {
                User newUser = new User();

                newUser.setId(id);
                newUser.setName((String) map.get("name"));
                newUser.setEmail((String) map.get("email"));
                newUser.setGender((String) map.get("gender"));
                newUser.setLocale((String) map.get("locale"));
                newUser.setUserpic((String) map.get("picture"));

                return newUser;
            });

            user.setLastVisit(LocalDateTime.now());

            return userRepo.save(user);
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Stop mixing jars from different versions of a Framework. Remove the `version` tag from the `org.springframework.boot` dependencies (the starters) as those are managed through the parent. You are mixing different versions that is trobuble waiting to happen.